# ASP.NET - Finding and Replacing a Dynamically Generated URL in Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I am working on an asp.net (C#) application where I need to parse and replace dynamically generated text.

A samle of the text is:
`onclick="javascript:EnterFolder('http:\u002f\u002fmyserver\u002fapps\u002fsitename\u002fsubsite1name?`

I need to replace it with :
`onclick="javascript:EnterFolder('http:\u002f\u002fmyserver\u002fapps\u002fsitename?`

Simply sinding and removing `subsite1` is not suitable because it exists in other parts of the text and is needed there.

I only wish to target and edit the urls preceded with: `javascript:EnterFolder('`

Please help

Comment: PS - There are at least 2 instances of the string in the text. I need to replace both. There are also other URLs in the text, but not preceded by " javascript:EnterFolder(' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression will work:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(origString, @"(javascript:EnterFolder\('http:\\u002f\\u002fmyserver\\u002fapps\\u002fsitename)\\u002fsubsite1name\?", "$1?");
```

Or, more general purpose:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(origString, @"(javascript:EnterFolder\('http:(.+?))\\u002fsubsite1name\?", "$1?");
```

Comment: Thank you both for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
onclick=\"javascript:EnterFolder\('http:\\[\w\\]+(\\\w+)\?
```

replace with

```
""
```